# Django - modify password hash before it is verified

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying using legacy, read only DB as django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser. Problem is that my legacy password field is SHA1 without starting 'sha1$$' string, just hash only, so I need to append extra string to every password.

models.py

```
class Tuzytkownik(AbstractBaseUser):
    login = models.CharField(db_column='LOGIN', max_length=50, unique=True)
    haslo = models.CharField(db_column='HASLO', max_length=50)
    password = 'sha1$$' + haslo
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'login'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Obviously

> password = 'sha1$$' + haslo

not working. How I can acheve it ?

To be specyfic - haslo returing 40charts hash like

> 'cf23df2207d99a74fbe169e3eba035e633b65d94'

what I need is

> 'sha1$$cf23df2207d99a74fbe169e3eba035e633b65d94'

Comment: you can override the default save method and set the password field there, refer this [Overriding predefined save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

Comment: my legacy DB is readonly ..save() save it on DB yes ?

Comment: No. That approach will not work, for several reasons. (You have to investigate how django model fields are implemented, and also how password hashing and authentication happens in django. Both are quite complicated) Since the db is read only, I think your best bet is to write a custom authentication backend class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Comment: Is there a simple way to write my model.CharField subclass to return what i need ?. AbstractBaseUser is just my backend. Don't want to write it from scrach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by overridding the [`AbstractBaseUser.set_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password) method ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L101-L111)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class Tuzytkownik(AbstractBaseUser):

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        # prepend the sha prefix before passing the hashed password to the hash checker
        return check_password(raw_password, 'sha1$$' + self.password)
```

Comment: I already did it this way, but could not find answer to original question - how to modify field within a model (like redefining save())